# Problem with conditional Probability with multiple conditions

Tags: classification, conditional-probability

I have classification setup with $r$ classes and three random variables:

- $T$: true category
- $F^A$: category assigned by the (fallible) classifier "A"
- $F^B$: category assigned by the (fallible) classifier "B"

For these, I have the following information:

- $p_i := P(T = i) \quad (i \in \{1, \ldots, r\})$
- $c^A_{ik} := P(F^A = k|T = i) \quad (i \in \{1, \ldots, r\}, \ k \in \{1, \ldots, r\})$
- $c^{B|A}_{kj} := P(F^B = j|F^A = k) \quad (j \in \{1, \ldots, r\}, \ k \in \{1, \ldots, r\})$

As a result, I have

$$
\pi^A_k := P(F^A = k) = \sum_{i = 1}^{r}{P(T = i) \, P(F^A = k|T = i)} = \sum_{i = 1}^{r}{p_i \ c^A_{ik}}
$$

and

$$
\pi^B_j := P(F^B = j) = \sum_{k = 1}^{r}{P(F^A = k) \, P(F^B = j|F^A = k)} = \sum_{k = 1}^{r}{\pi^A_k \ c^{B|A}_{kj}}\\ = \sum_{k = 1}^{r}{\sum_{i = 1}^{r}{p_i \ c^A_{ik}} \ c^{B|A}_{kj}} = \sum_{i = 1}^{r}{p_i \ \sum_{k = 1}^{r}{c^A_{ik}} \ c^{B|A}_{kj}}\\[30pt]
$$

With vectors $p = (p_1, ..., p_r)^T$, $\pi^A = (\pi^A_1, ..., \pi^A_r)^T$, $\pi^B = (\pi^B_1, ..., \pi^B_r)^T$, and matrices $C^A = (c^A_{ik})_{1 \leq i, k \leq r}$ and $C^{B|A} = (c^{B|A}_{kj})_{1 \leq k, j \leq r}$, the above expressions are equivalent to

$$
(\pi^A)^T = p^T \, C^A \quad \text{and} \quad (\pi^B)^T = (\pi^A)^T \, C^{B|A} \, = p^T \, C^A \, C^{B|A}
$$

So far, so good. Quite simple stuff. Now, I want to compute $c^B_{ij} := P(F^B = j|T = i)$. Using the law of total probability and the definition of conditional probabilities, I get

$$
P(F^B = j | T = i) = \sum_{k = 1}^{r}{P(F^B = j | F^A = k \wedge T = i) \, P(F^A = k|T = i)}.
$$

From simulations (and intuition, because of the last matrix product of $(\pi^B)^T$), I concluded something slightly different:

$$
P(F^B = j | T = i) = \sum_{k = 1}^{r}{P(F^B = j | F^A = k) \, P(F^A = k|T = i)}.
$$

The big question here: why is $P(F^B = j | F^A = k \wedge T = i) = P(F^B = j | F^A = k)$? The most simple answer would be that $T$ is independent of $F^A$ and $F^B$, but this is usually not true. What other reasons could there be? And how can I prove it? The sum expression of $\pi^B_j$ (and the matrix expression of $\pi^B$) is not sufficient (, right?).

Maybe you could provide me with links to some publications that already dealt with that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your information is insufficient to solve the problem, since you have not specified the statistical relationship between $F^B$ and $T$, conditional on $F^A$.  If you are willing to assume conditional independence then you have:

$$F^B \bot \text{ } T | F_A \quad \quad \iff \quad \quad \mathbb{P}(F^B=b |F^A=a) = \mathbb{P}(F^B=b|F^A=a, T=t)$$

In other words, making the probability equation you are using in your analysis  is equivalent to assuming that the random variables $F^B$ and $T$ are conditionally independent given $F^A$.  This means that once you already know $F^A$, your knowledge of the behaviour of $F^B$ is not affected by the true state $T$.  If this is a reasonable assumption in your analysis then the use of that equation is acceptable.